# Sending identities to identities while defining homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

When we define a homomorphism $f:A \rightarrow B$, sometimes we have to give that $f(1_A)=1_B$ where $1_A=$ the identity of $A$ and $1_B=$ the identity of $B$.
 Lang gives that while defining monoid homomorphism. Also he says that a group homomorphism is simply a monoid homomorphism. We also note that while defining a ring homomorphism.
 I have 2 questions:

1)Why Lang says that $f(1_A)=1_B$ by mentioning that a group homomorphism is a monoid-homomorphism?

2)Do we need $f(1_A)=1_B$ only when we have some structure which is not closed under multiplication, given that $1$'s are the multiplicative identities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For groups, you only need the condition $f(ab)=f(a) f(b)$. From there, it follows that $f(1)=1$ (and also $f(a^{-1})=f(a)^{-1}$).

For other structures, namely when inverses do not exist for all elements (like monoids, rings, algebras, etc.), the implication does not hold automatically, so you have to impose it additionally if you want to. For example some authors define a ring-homomorphism without the condition, and then talk about "unital ring homomorphisms", when they need it.

Comment: By saying that 'when inverses do not exist' you mean the multiplicative inverses, right?

Comment: Yes. In order to show f(1)=1 you need Multiplucative inverses. If you wanted to show f(0)=0 you would need additive inverse (in rings or algebras, where you have both operations. In groups there is of course only one operation)

Comment: Finally, when do we need $1 \neq 0$ in the definition of some structure?

Comment: The only structure where that can happen is the ring with exactly one element (the "zero ring"). As soon as there is a second element, it can not happen anymore (note that in some definitions of" ring", there might not exist a 1 at all). Also this zero-ring is such an annoying example that many theorems and definitions (including the definition of "domain" and "field") explicitly exclude it.

Comment: So if we note that the structure is not "zero structure" then we do not need to mention $1 \neq 0$, otherwise we do, right?

Comment: Thank you for all the help.